# python appium with appPacake ID failed to create session

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, appium

I'm trying app automation with Python Appium, but the appPackage I'm using is 'id' instead of 'com'. When I run the Appium server and also Appium inspector, I encounter an error message that says, 'Failed to create session. An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start the 'id.dana' application.

my desired capability:

```
{
  "appium:appPackage": "id.dana",
  "appium:appActivity": "id.dana.onboarding.IntroductionActivity",
  "platformName": "Android",
  "appium:deviceName": "xxx",
  "appium:uuid": "xxx"
}
```

My hope is to succeed in inspecting the elements of the application and automating them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.